# Accessing geometry of object that is inherited from a mixin?

Tags: aframe

When I've got a sphere which is defined largely using a mixin, e.g.

```
<a-mixin id="beach-ball" geometry="primitive: sphere; radius: 1"></a-mixin>
```

And used like so:

```
<a-entity mixin="beach-ball" id="beach-ball-main"></a-entity>
```

Is there a way I can then find out the radius of the beach ball using JS while the scene is running? Attempts at doing this don't work:

```
var ballRadius = document.getElementById('beach-ball-main').getAttribute('geometry').radius;
```

... that just returns a blank geometry attribute, which makes sense as the entity itself doesn't have the geometry defined.

However, surely there's a way to request the current radius of the ball in the above example, even though it's defined in a mixin?

All help appreciated!

Comment: Which version of A-Frame are you on? The recent versions should work with `.getAttribute()`. If you are on an older version, you'd use `.getComputedAttribute()`.

Comment: Ah ha! It must have been an older version of A-Frame. I updated to 0.5.0 and `getAttribute` appears to be working a-okay! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`getAttribute()` works as long as you have an up to date version of A-Frame!

Comment: And `.getComputedAttribute()` if you have an old one (like `0.2.0`)